# Why can I use nullptr without including STL?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stl, nullptr

The C++ **nullptr** is of the type **std::nullptr_t**.

Why does a program like

```
int main() {
 int* ptr = nullptr;
}
```

still work, although it doesn't include any STL library?

Comment: Because `nullptr` is a keyword of the language much like `int`.

Comment: What library do you believe would need including here?

Comment: some STL library like iostream.h, which includes then references to the type definition of the nullptr.

Comment: yes, nullptr is a keyword, but why would that keyword work when its type is not known?

Comment: @RobertHönig *The C++ nullptr is of the type std::nullptr_t.* Actually its the other way around, from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t): `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;`

Comment: @RobertHönig Because you're not naming that type.

Comment: @Borgleader that's it, thank you :)

Comment: @RobertHönig : <iostream.h> and the STL were two distinct libraries that both were included in Standard C++. The third major library included in C++ is the Standard Library from C. And `std::nullptr_t` came from neither; it's a C++11 invention.

Comment: `<iostream.h>` was present in some (early) drafts of the C++ standard, but was never in a ratified standard.

Comment: It is because `nullptr` is a keyword-specified literal like `false` and `true`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++11 they wanted to add a keyword to replace the macro `NULL` (which is basically defined as `#define NULL 0`), both because it is a core concept, and because of some annoying bugs you get when you are forced to use `0` as your null pointer constant.

A number of keywords where proposed.  Large codebases where searched to ensure that the keyword was not in use, and that it still described what they wanted (a null pointer constant).

`nullptr` was found to be sufficiently rare and evocative enough.

The type of `nullptr` was not given a keyword name by default, because that wasn't required for most programs.  You can get it via `decltype(nullptr)` or including a `std` header and using `std::nullptr_t`.