# Why is nullptr a part of the core language, but nullptr_t is a part of STL?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

As far as I'm aware `nullptr` is a part of the core language.

Quoting C++11: (18.2/9)

> `nullptr_t` is defined as follows:
>
> `namespace std { typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t; }`

and is defined in the header `<cstddef>`.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080709/why-can-i-use-nullptr-without-including-stl

Comment: You don't need `nullptr_t` if you are willing to live with `decltype(nullptr)`. `nullptr_t` isn't a core concept, it's a helper.

Comment: You need `nullptr_t` sometimes: "If two or more overloads accept different pointer types, an overload for `std::nullptr_t` is necessary to accept a null pointer argument." (cppreference for std::nullptr_t).

Comment: @Adrian I'm assuming you meant to reply to my comment. If so, I said you don't need `nullptr_t` **if you are willing to live with `decltype(nullptr)`**. You can use `decltype(nullptr)` instead of `nullptr_t`. `nullptr_t` is just a convenient alias for `decltype(nullptr);`. You *should* use `nullptr_t`,  my comment is meant to indicate why `nullptr_t` might not be part of the core language.

Comment: Also by making `nullptr` part of the language, it is much easier to ensure that it works as it should because you can easily have specific rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proposal that introduced `nullptr`, [N2431](https://wg21.link/n2431), indicates in section 1.1 that it was desirable to not force users to include a header in order to use `nullptr`.

It also remarks, "We do not expect to see much direct use of `nullptr_t` in real programs". Thus, it was considered preferable to add `nullptr_t` to the library rather than create a new keyword only to be used for this obscure purpose. In addition, if you don't want to include the header, you can always just write `decltype(nullptr)` yourself.

Comment: this actually answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

Because it can.  A central aim in the C++ standardization process is to alter the core language as little as possible when adding to the language.

`nullptr` usurps the use of `0` to mean both a null pointer and, er, zero. Using `0` for both caused problems for obvious reasons, does `f(0)` call `f(int)` or `f(int*)`?  So a brand new literal was added to the core language: `nullptr`.  Its type is simply `decltype(nullptr)` so `nullptr_t` was added as a short cut:

```
namespace std {
    using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the nullptr itself can be a part of the STL... Is nullptr included in the core language to not require developers to include any header files?

Comment: @embedc Any `std` typedefs like e.g. `std::stize_t`are provided through headers, so what?

Comment: @embedc `nullptr` is a literal like `5`, `'a'` or `"hello"`. While I can't imagine what it is, I would bet there is a good technical reason why a null pointer literal is better than having a `nullptr`-like object in `std`. Edit : For one thing, being a literal it's a prvalue so you can't take it's address. It would seem strange to me to be able to take `nullptr`'s address. It would be like getting `true`'s address.

Comment: No headers are required. It is a built-in keyword / pointer literal.

Answer (score 1):

*From cppreference.com:*

> std::nullptr_t is the **type of the null pointer literal**, nullptr. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type.
>
> If two or more overloads accept different pointer types, **an overload for std::nullptr_t is necessary to accept a null pointer argument**.

You can then solve overloaded function call ambiguity with `std::nullptr_t`.

For example:

```cpp
void Foo(int* ptr) {}
void Foo(double* ptr) {}
void Foo(std::nullptr_t ptr) {} // This overload is called if Foo(nullptr) is invoked
```

Read more about `std::nullptr_t` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t